# Auto-organize Visual Studio Tabs?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

Is there any setting in Visual Studio 2008 to group/organize tabs?  For example, I'd prefer to have all code-behind files open in a tab next to its .aspx page if that page is open and vice versa. Dragging tabs around really kills my productivity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jonathan,

[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) (developed by me) add-in can automatically group .aspx and .aspx.cs windows in one tab.

Comment: +1 great time-saving VS add-in, does exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Check ot this link - it explains how to make the active tab jump to the left-most position, thereby effectively keeping the most used tabs from 'falling off': [window tab management in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2007/04/13/window-tab-management-in-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.  I tried it but couldn't get used to it.  From what I've read, many agree that there needs to be an overhaul of how VS tabs work in general.

Comment: It has worked beautifully for me.  I bumbled into this many months ago, and was trying to re-find it for my new computer.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting for this, but take a look at the documentation for writing visual studio add-ins. This would be a pretty simple one to set up.